# Implement dictionary using apache solr

Tags: python, dictionary, solr, schema

I have to implement a dictionary using apache solr 4.8 so that it can be avaiable on a website for word definations. I have defined a simple solr schema for it. Its major fields are

```
<field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" required="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
<field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true" />
```

Search field is title only

It some how solve my problem but there is an issue with it. There are some proverbs in dictionary also.There is a proverb **wealthy and wise** in dictionary also.  Suppose I enter **wealthy** , I expect solr should give result from exact word wealthy but actually it also shows its result from proverb defination.

How to fix it? Should I change schema or apply some filter ?

Note: Actual implementation of dictionary for solr is not for English language but a local language. But I am facing similar problem as I explained above.

Comment: How are you running the search?  Are you generating the search string yourself or are you using an API call?  It would be helpful to know what search string Solr is processing.  Also, you may need to weight your title field more heavily.

Comment: Its an API that I am using to call solr for results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a new field type using keywordTokenizerFactory.

`Guide about tokenizer can be found from` [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers)

Chnage your schema like following.
In schema.xml file

```
   <fieldType name="exactstring" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
..........
..........
<field name="title" type="exactstring" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```